# Java regex Matcher: are the following equivalent?

Tags: java, regex

Using `java.util.regex.Matcher`, are the following expressions for `matched1` and `matched2` equivalent?  Is there a simpler way to get a value for `matched`?

```
StringBuilder b = ...
Pattern p = ...
Matcher m = p.matcher(b);
m.find();


String matched1 = b.substring(m.start(), m.end());

String matched2 = m.group();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent, and no, there is no simpler way.

I'd prefer the `.group()` approach; perhaps wrapped in an `if (m.find())` conditional.

Comment: e.g. `String matched = m.find()? m.group(): ""`?

Comment: @Alison: Good idea, if you like the ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

they are equal. you can find all matched like this.

```
   while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
        System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
  }
```